# Find the volume of the resulting solid (understanding to find radius)

Tags: calculus

The region $R$ enclosed by the curves $y=x$ and $y=x^2$ is rotated about the $x$-axis. Find the volume of the resulting solid.

Solution. The curves $y=x$ and $y=x^2$ intersect at the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. The region between them, the solid of rotation, and a cross-section perpendicular to the $x$-axis are shown in the plane $P_x$ has the shape of a washer with inner radius $x^2$ and outer radius $x$, so we find the cross-sectional area by subtracting the area of the circle of the inner circle from the area of the outer circle ...bla bla.

**My question is**: Why inner radius is $x^2$ and outer radius is $x$? Why not inner radius is $x$ and outer radius is $x^2$ Can you explain?

Comment: For $0\le x \le1$ we have $x^2\le x$.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the graphs:

[image]

Or algebraically, if $0<x<1$, then $x^2 = x \cdot x < x \cdot 1 = x$.

Answer (score 0):

Over the region of interest, $0 \le x \le 1,$ we have $x^2 \le x$ with equality only at the endpoints, so $x^2$ is closer to the $x$ axis than $x$ and is therefore the inner radius.  There is a tendency to think of squaring as making things larger but not when they are less than $1$ in absolute value.